# How to make partition in large volume for internal hdd?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have acer win7 laptop with 640gb hdd. I want to make large volume like 350gb for the other partition but I can make only 73gb >_< I need to save my document before I reformat it. So how can I make 350gb for my partition? thanks in advance =)

Comment: You shoud use gparted tool for editing partitions.

Comment: How to use it? Is it complicated?

Comment: See this [full tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html) on GParted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ubuntu under your win7 OS then resize your partition via the instructions given on the page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk.